# Php error in mb_send_mail

Tags: php, sendmail, quoted-printable

I have got:

`mb_send_mail(): Unsupported transfer encoding "quoted-printable" - will be regarded as 8bit`

What should I do?

Full headers:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Thu, 17 Mar 2011 19:17:48 +0200
Message-ID: <1300382268.4d82423c6c409@mydomain.com>
From: noreply@mydomain.com
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?=D0=9D=D0=BE=D0=B2=D1=8B=D0=B9_=D0=BA=D0=BE?=
 =?utf-8?Q?=D0=BC=D0=BC=D0=B5=D0=BD=D1=82=D0=B0=D1=80?=
 =?utf-8?Q?=D0=B8=D0=B9_=D0=BA_=D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=88?=
 =?utf-8?Q?=D0=B5=D0=B9_=D1=84=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=BE=D0=B3?=
 =?utf-8?Q?=D1=80=D0=B0=D1=84=D0=B8=D0=B8?=
To: some@email.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

[PEAR Bug #10146 - mbstring fails to recognize encodings.](http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=10146)

Comment: It's dated 2007. And I have to use mb_overload=7. Where I have to look for the answer? :)

Comment: setting mbstring.func_overload = 2 and now it works... I hate PHP :)

Comment: "It's dated 2007" => what's the problem ? However I agree that `func_overload=7` wouldn't be great... Have you tried the last proposal ('Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit') or other encodings (http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1521/5.htm) if possible for you ?